# How do you copy and paste rich text to and from the wxRichTextCtrl?

Tags: ruby, wxwidgets, copy-paste, rte, wxruby

I am using wxruby but as far as I can tell its not only a ruby problem. If I try to copy and paste rich text into the wxRichTextCtrl it loses all the formatting. What am I missing? Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [SVN trunk code](http://svn.wxwidgets.org/viewvc/wx/wxWidgets/trunk/src/richtext/richtextbuffer.cpp?view=markup) for *richtextbuffer.cpp*, in particular the method

```
bool wxRichTextBuffer::PasteFromClipboard(long position)
```

the control accepts exactly 4 different clipboard formats:

- its own private format *wxRichTextBufferDataObject::GetRichTextBufferFormatId()*
- standard text formats *wxDF_TEXT* and *wxDF_UNICODETEXT*
- a bitmap format *wxDF_BITMAP*

So it is indeed possible to copy and paste rich text between different or within a single *wxRichTextCtrl*, but there is no support for pasting RTF or similar data from external applications into a *wxRichTextCtrl*.